# When and where the cutting plane method should be applied?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cutting-planes

As the cutting plan algorithm is a method to strengthen the feasible space of the linear programming, specifically in the MILP problems to invoke the integer solutions, it may be a problem-based specific method in which how they can be added to the model. I know that for many of the problems, it is possible to add different kinds of cuts to get the same integer solution at least for an indexed variable. (e.g. either using a Gomory fractional cut or MIR cut to solve an IP/MIP problem as shown in [this](https://www.scipopt.org/download/slides/SCIP-cuttingPlanes.pdf) link).

Now, if anyone wants to use a cutting plane scheme on the problem that needs to solve with a specific method like branch-cut, relaxed-cut, etc, is there any way to find out which one of the cuts should be used to make the better results? Another question that is rising to my mind is, how do mathematical solvers distinguish when and where a specific cut should be applied?

Any insight about that would be helpful.

Comment: Trial and error?

Comment: @prubin, I think, there should be a specific procedure to adding the cuts to the MP, specifically MIP, as many of the commercial/open-source solvers have such a capability!? And this would be really more than trial and error. What's your idea?

Comment: There may be certain properties of the constraint matrix that lead a solver to try certain kinds of cuts. My impression with commercial solvers is that they are somewhat adaptive: if one type of cut seems to be helping and another type is not as productive, they may try more often to find the first type of cut and less often to find the second type (subject to being overridden by a parameter setting).

Comment: Have you seen "Learning to Select Cuts for Efficient Mixed-Integer
Programming" https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13645.pdf ? There  are a lot of efforts underway, with I believe some commercial MILP solver implementations, for using machine learning to improve cut strategies, as well as B&B branching variable and node selection, pruning, etc.

Comment: @prubin, Many thanks. I totally agree with your first phrase. Would you please, do you know any reference about that? Let's say, I have tried to solve some problems (IP/MIP) by SCIP to understand which one of the cuts would be applied to which kind of the problems. The results were interesting as for example, on a MIP problem I expect to add some cuts like MIR, but it applied some of Gomory cuts. Also, as far as I know, there are some parameters to control the behavior of how a cut can be added, but I do not have any experience with those.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, Thanks a lot for your comments. It is really interesting. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any references about which cuts to apply and when to apply them. I'll second what @MarkL.Stone said about solver designers trying to use machine learning, either by running ML on their library of test problems to develop rules that are then embedded in the solver or maybe by baking some ML into the solver itself. (I think it's more the former right now.)

Comment: I don't have time to write a detailed answer, but I think that what you're looking for is in Tobias Achtenberg PhD thesis https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/1112/file/Achterberg_Constraint_Integer_Programming.pdf in particular in section 3.3.8

Comment: @fontanf, many thanks for your comment and the mentioned reference.